# OpenCV Python save jpg specifying quality; gives SystemError

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg

I just installed the newest OpenCV 2.4 on windows 7 (32bit)/ Python 2.7.3,
 but I still get the same error I got using the beta version:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> a = cv2.imread(r"DMap.jpg")
>>> a.shape
(1080, 1920, 3)
>>> cv2.imwrite('img_CV2_90.jpg', a, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 90])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

Any ideas ?  Using tuple instead of list, or adding a trailing 0 to the sequence does not help - same error.

Thanks
- Sebastian Haase

Comment: did you remove all traces of the old package before installing the new one ?

Comment: yes. As far as I can tell, I have only PYTHONPATH and PATH set into the c:/OpenCV2.4 directory. 
--- 
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\opencv2.4\build\x86\mingw\bin
---
maybe that's the problem .... should I point to vc9 or vc10 instead of mingw ???

Comment: when you do import cv2, and the then cv2.__file__ do you really see it is the new version ?

Comment: >>> cv2.__file__  ==> 
'C:\opencv2.4\build\python\2.7\cv2.pyd'

Comment: And I just also tried changing the PATH variable to point to  C:\opencv2.4\build\x86\vc8\bin ---  and then to ...vc9... --- both no change..

Comment: Whoops --- just noticed that ..vc8..  doesn't even exists !!  Tried vc10 --  no change ....     why did it work when I used vc8 ?? And which SHOULD I use with python.org Python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is probably due to some wrong wrapping of the `imwrite()` parameters from Python to C, `cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY` (which is of type "long"), and causes some weird problems. You should try to convert this constant to "int" type:

```
cv2.imwrite('img_CV2_90.jpg', a, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])
```

for me it solved the problem (python 2.7.2, opencv 2.4.1)

Comment: this should be filed as a bug

Comment: Can we convert the quality without writing the image? I want to calculate `cv2.absdiff` between the original image and the converted image on a dataset with 500 000 images. so if I skip the io part, it would be more efficient.

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam maybe try `cv2.imencode()` instead, I'd guess it has the same params as `imwrite`, you can use `imdecode` after and avoid using the disk and save some io.