# How to compress png file with opencv in python?

Tags: image, python-3.x, numpy, opencv3.0

I tried this code:

```
compression_params = [cv2.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9] 
img = cv2.imread('img1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
cv2.imwrite('compress_img1.png', img, compression_params)
```

But I obtain this error:

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION'

I'm working with python 3.5 and opencv 3.0

Comment: Did you import opencv (cv2)? `import cv2`

Comment: Have you tried `from cv2.cv import CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The name in OpenCV 3.0 is [`IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42acad2548321c69ab9c0582fd51e75ace1d0) (without the `CV_` prefix).

So try:

```
cv2.imwrite('compress_img1.png', img,  [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9])
```

---

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335576/5008845) mentions also to cast to `int`. I'm not sure if this is still needed:

```
cv2.imwrite('compress_img1.png', img,  [int(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION), 9])
```

Comment: Both ones worked, didn't see any difference. Maybe on some systems the IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION would be a float, then the int() would be needed

Comment: @WoodyDRN The PNG format is lossless so the resulting image is always exactly the same. The only difference is processing speed (0 being the fastest).

Comment: WARNING! Do not use option 9! It was almost 20x slower for me in HR images, it took me a while to figure out there were other faster settings. Check level "0".

Comment: @RafaelToledo that's bad advice. Like many compression methods, with PNG you give a number between 0-9 to trade off computation time against file size. Level 9 is often a good choice as it gives you the smallest files at the cost of more computation. Level 0 does no compression and leads to huge files, which makes one question why you are using PNG at all.